# CSS Cascading HTML5 <header> <nav> elements - How?

Tags: css, html

Example:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>...</ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header nav { ... } /* does not work */
```

Is there any way possible?

Comment: That is supposed to work. Is your HTML really structured like that? What browsers are you testing on? If old IE, you need the [HTML5 shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Comment: @Bolt how about a link or something explaining the HTML5 shiv?

Comment: @JMC Creative: Was getting to that, fixed now.

Comment: header nav ul { clear: both; } does the job ... header nav {} would be nice

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Your question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an ordered list for your nav header just for a more semantic page.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work (which it should), try this:

`header > nav { .. }`

Best of luck!